# Store data other than a file

Tags: java, java-io

I want to store some data in Java so that I can read it in another class. Currently what I do is I create a txt file, store the data there, and read that file from the other classes. What output stream should I use if I do not want to display the data by storing it as a txt file? I want to be able to save it in the memory so that other classes can read it? How do I do this?

Comment: You can use `hsql db` http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/apb.html of course also some small one-file db like `SQLite`.

Comment: I want to be able to use only Java API. I do not have a DB yet

Comment: How about storing the data as a class then accessing the class when you need the data?

Comment: In that case, create Singleton collection that will be accessed/stored only from one place and bootstraped from file one time when application is starting.

Comment: I am using a third party API to format the data in some other format that only takes in OutputStream object. So, I had to use file and thus cannot use a class

Comment: Subclass OutputStream

Comment: well then you can store your data in a class and then use ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: Why do you need an output stream? Those are useful for process-to-process communication, for use by two classes within the same application, why not just call `yourClass.getData()` and use the data directly?

Comment: @Rafik Since Java 6 the JDK has shipped with Apache Derby. HSQL DB is, I'm sure, far faster, but for a simple use case one can just go with what's in the JDK.